# How to get UI5 control?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am trying to add a new Button in Toolbar dynamically, but fail to call addContent of Toolbar control. Is `UI5 control` a special type just like `jQuery object`? How to get access to it ?

my Code:

```
$("footer").control().addContent(new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Disconnect"
}))
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nekixoq/6/edit?html,output) (In jsbin I use JSView to initialize control , but in reality, I use XMLView instead. And call addContent in my Controller)

Ref:  http://scn.sap.com/thread/3538452 
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Toolbar.html#addContent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not invoke `addContent` on `DOM` elements, as it is method to be invoked on `SAPUI5` controls.

To add content dynamically from controller, access `Toolbar` with it's `id` like this:

```
this.getView().byId("toolbarId").addContent(new sap.m.Button({
    text: "Disconnect"
}));
```

Comment: What if the function is invoke by button, and `this` scope changed ?  `sap.ui.getCore().byId('__xmlview0').byId("toolbarId")` not work...

Comment: `this` won't change if you invoke function in `press` event handler. Even if `this` has changed in any other case you can always access control with `sap.ui.getCore().byId("toolbarId")`, and this is `sap.ui.getCore().byId('__xmlview0').byId("toolbarId")` incorrect. Have a look at [byId()](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html#byId) in `API` of `sap.ui.core.Core`

Comment: Thanks, it works ~